# Loop through all nodes with rules

Tags: 7, rules, entities

I have a content type (called **Contact List**) and by using [Rules](http://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module I want to check if there is a specific phone number in my nodes, I get the node id and use it in the other content type (called **Products** which has an *Entity Reference* field that point to the **contact list**).

if not and it can't find any entries I create a **contact list** node.

Certainly the phone number field is unique.

How can this be done with Action loop?

[image]

As in the picture depicted I need to add some functionality that check the Contact list existence to prevent duplication.

Comment: You can find tens of tutorials (video also) dealing with this subject. For complex conditional rule logic also look at [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional)

Comment: what would your React on Event be?

Comment: Thanks Reynolds, I check most of them but they can't help to reach my aim.

Comment: Hi No Sssweat, after updating the entityform submission, I'm updating my question with the picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a case for the Rules action:

"Fetch entity by property"

It will allow you to load another entity using a particular value, such as phone number.

Comment: Cheers mate You are amazing